# Bash: ./configure: No such file or directory, despite having installed all build essentials

Tags: bash, 22.04, error-handling

I am having trouble while installing a .tar.gz application. I have all build essentials installed and update. What the error could be?

Comment: Did you expand the tarball? and was `.configure`  a file within it? as otherwise it's the incorrect command.  We only know what you tell us, and you've provided no details about what tarball (.tar.gz) you're asking about.

Comment: Are you in the right directory ?

Comment: Is that the application source code of unix compilation? if yes, you need to run `autoconf` to make `configure` file or run `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..` to build using cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be different things.

1. The `.tar.gz` is not an archive conventionally packaged to contain source code to build the program. In fact, a `.tar.gz` as such is just an archive format just like `.zip`, so in principle can contain anything. *Thus, first, check if you have the right archive.*
2. Your current working directory is not the directory where the `configure` script of the archive resides. *Thus, make sure the current working directory is the one where the contents of the archive has been unpacked*. You should see its name in the output of the command `ls`, the directory listing.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I made it work as you told after doing some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are on Unix compilation source files. after you change directory in Working Directory you can make `.configure` file using:

1. **Autoconf**
   To make configure file from autoconf, make sure you have `configure.ac` and `aclocal.m4` nor `acsite.m4` files. their will generated to `config.in` and `.configure`. see [Autoconf Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/index.html)
2. **Automake**
   Additionally. if you're using Automake, make sure you have 'Makefile.am' file to generated to `Makefile.in` for scanning `configure.ac` with `aclocal.m4` to determine of information package and it will creating `Makefile` file being the default target in build system. see [Automake Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html)

**Related**

- http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/
- http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/automake.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/libtool.html

Thanks.